# Why requireJS is not appending '.js' in module names

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My following code:

```
require(['/AppScripts/book/properties'], function (mod) {
    ...
});
```

fails because it is sending get request with no .js in url as under:
http://localhost:182/AppScripts/book/properties

Similarly, define too fails for same reason:

```
define(["require", "exports", "global"], function (require, exports, global_1) {
    ...
});
```

generates http://localhost:182/global that misses .js

I double checked both urls by adding '.js' and they found required scripts.

Here is my config:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../Scripts/lib/jquery',
        requirejs: '../Scripts/lib/require',
    }
});
```

All the docs and references that I could find say the extension is automatically appended but not in my case. My problem is, this code is being generated by TypeScript compiler so I can't add extensions manually. It must be handled by  requireJS.

Can somebody please help what I am missing? Thanks.

**Edit**
Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "AMD",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "../AppScripts",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    //"watch": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": [ "TypeScripts/typings/*" ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "TypeScripts/typings"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "TypeScripts/typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us your tsconfig

Comment: @Jared Smith, added tsconfig in edit.

Comment: That is interesting! What version of RequireJS do you use?

Comment: Here is the line which appends or not a extension: https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L1674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requirejs treats path starting from "/" as absolute so does not append anything to the left or right of the string whereas I was looking for relative path that must not start from "/". changing **require(['/AppScripts/book/properties']** to **require(['AppScripts/book/properties']** solves problem.